# Recycler View horizontal doesn't scroll till the end

Tags: android, xamarin, scroll, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have a RecyclerView that loads a list of images in a horizontal scroll view. On addition of every item, I scroll the position to the last item but only a small portion of the last item becomes visible and the rest of the part stays hidden.

Any tips on how to scroll till the end so that the last item is fully visible?

The code from the Adapter which loads a new image in the item:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        var viewHolder = holder as CustomViewHolder;
        viewHolder.cardView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

        Picasso.With(viewHolder.imgViewIcon.Context).Load("file:///" + mItemsData[position]).Into(viewHolder.imgViewIcon, new ImageLoadCallback(viewHolder));
        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.Tag = position;
    }
```

This one saves the image to SD Card and adds the item to the data source of the recyclerview and notifies the items change:

```
private void AddImageASync(int rotation, byte[] data) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            Bitmap bmp = rotatePicture(rotation, data);
            Android.Net.Uri photoUri = ImageUtility.savePicture(Activity, bmp);
            mImageItems.Add(photoUri.Path);
        }).ContinueWith(task => {
            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                mAdapter.NotifyItemInserted(mImageItems.Count - 1);
                mRecyclerView.ScrollToPosition(mImageItems.Count - 1);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is it impossible to manually scroll to the end? You might have to show us a video or some code.

Comment: There's no way to know what's going on until we see your code.

Comment: Manually scroll is fine, I use the method scrollToPosition(lastItem) and it shows a small portion of the last item. Adding code as well.

Comment: @FarazHassan found any solution for that? i believe i am stuck at the same thing